# Is there a way to access Flight Data Recorder information for major incidents?

Tags: commercial-aviation, accidents, accident-statistics

I am working on a school project where I am hoping to use by-second data from flight 1549 (miracle on the hudson). Is there a way/place to acquire flight data recorder information for these major accidents? NTSB seems to be offline and has been for quite a while. Thanks